# How to get from the preceeding line to the next?

Tags: sequences-and-series

upon expanding series the first two terms are 1-e^(psi) but the value on the denominator is positive for the e term. I am struggling to understand why only the first two terms are being used of the series and secondly how they got to the denominator ?

[image]

Comment: Mostly irrelevant, but for your general information: $$\text{psi}=\psi\\ \text{xi}=\xi\\ \text{chi}=\chi$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Geometric series, for $|r|<1:$ $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty r^m= \frac{1}{1-r}$$ Take $r=-e^{-\xi}$, then $\xi>0$ so $|r|<1$ and thus $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty r^m=\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-e^{-\xi})^m=\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^me^{-m\xi}=\frac{1}{1-(-e^{-\xi})}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\xi}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is a geometric sum:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^me^{-m\xi} = \lim_{M\to +\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{M} (-1)^m(e^{-\xi})^m = \lim_{M\to +\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{M} (-e^{-\xi})^m = \lim_{M\to +\infty} \frac{1-(-e^{-\xi})^{M+1}}{1-(-e^{-\xi})} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\xi}}.$$
(If $\xi>0$ then $e^{-\xi}\in [0;1[$. If $\xi<0$, this series is divergent...)

Comment: Could the downvoter explain his/her vote, please?

Answer (score 0):

Set $u=\mathrm e^{-\xi}$ and expand  $\;\dfrac 1{1+u}$.